# Is $J_1$ a subquotient of the monster group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, monster

Edit:  I was able to make a 3D diagram of the happy family if anyone is interested!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4IjnIcECoQ

I'm working on a twitter thread about the monster group, because I saw an interview with John Conway and he was very interested in the monster group.

Here is a link to the wikipedia article on the monster:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_group

I'm very interested in the diagram of the sporadic groups.  (Also if anyone would like to provide some basic understanding of the sporadic groups that would be helpful.) I'm trying to make a 3D version of the diagram with wire...

When I look at the diagram [image: sproadic groups diagram]

I can understand that the sporadic groups that are maximal are the ones that are circled. And $M$ is the monster, with $B$ the baby monster. And it looks like $J_1$ is a subquotient of the maximal group $O'N$.  I'm not very familiar with subquotients, so I am wondering if $J_1$ is a subquotient of $M$?  That is, for my purposes, do I need to include $O'N$ and $J_1$ in the diagram of the monster?

Comment: Note for readers: the diagram (copied from the Wikipedia page) represents the "be isomorphic to a subquotient of" relation. More precisely I guess that there an edge between $A$ and $B$ with $A$ below $B$ if $A$ is isomorphic to a subquotient of $B$, and there's no other sporadic group "in between", but the caption is not more precise than "showing subquotient relationship".

Comment: Curious: "Code golf" on Monster group: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203524/conways-monster

Comment: By the way I guess that it might happen that there are other simple groups "in between". That is, a non-sporadic simple group involved in some larger sporadic group, and involving some smaller sporadic group.

Comment: @YCor I haven't checked thoroughly but I don't believe that there are any examples in the diagram where there are any other simple groups in between, but they are not all maximal subgroups, and some are genuinely quotients of subgroups. For example,  it is the double cover $2.{\rm B}$ rather than ${\rm B}$ itself that is a subgroup of M, and the extension $2^{11}.{\rm  M }_{24}$ is a maximal subgroup of ${\rm J}_4$.

Comment: @DerekHolt this would be nice (it would say that the "set" of sporadic groups is "convex" among finite simple groups).

Comment: @DerekHolt $G_2(4)$ is "in between" $J_2$ and $Suz$.

Comment: Ah right, I missed that!

Comment: @YCor  Thank you for the clarification, I want to be able to explain the diagram.  So, I would say that, for example, the baby monster group is isomorphic to a subquotient of the monster group?

Comment: @AlexanderChervov thanks for the link!  That looks very interesting.

Comment: @DerekHolt Also, when I say that in the diagram the monster group is maximal, maximal with respect to what?  The monster group is maximal with respect to sporadic groups?

Comment: I am not sure why you are asking me what you mean by what you have written! It means they are maximal in the sense that they are not proper subquotients of any larger sporadic groups.

Comment: @DerekHolt I see thank you very much! They are not proper subquotients of any larger sporadic groups.  Are you talking about the order of the groups dividing each other?

Comment: No not at all. $A$ is (isomorphic to) a subquotient of $B$ if there is a subgroup $C$ of $B$ and a normal subgroup $N$ of $C$ such that $C/N \cong A$. Then $A$ is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of $B$ if we can choose $N=1$; i.e. if there exists $C \le B$ with $A \cong C$.

Comment: That is really helpful, I think I am getting closer to getting it.  Then the groups do not sit inside each other, but they can be isomorphic to a part of the other one.  I will definitely include this.

Comment: I see because these are simple groups.

Comment: Nice sculpture!! It's cool to see such abstract theory represented physically...

Comment: @NickGill  Thank you!! It is a cool way to learn about the diagram!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No $J_1$ is not involved in (i.e. is not a subquotient of) the Monster.

The six sporadic simple groups listed [here](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/spor/) as "Pariahs" are precisely those that are not involved in the Monster, namely $J_1$,   O'N,    $J_3$,     Ru,     $J_4$,     Ly.

There is a lot of information about the Monster and its subgroups in Section 5.8 of Robert Wilson's book, "The Finite Simple Groups''.

Note that, apart from a few uncertainties about a few possible groups ${\rm PSL}_2(q)$ for some small values of $q$, the maximal subgroups of the Monster are now all known, so locating which other simple groups are involved in it is moderately straightforward, using the ATLAS of Finite Simple Groups or the weblink above.

In fact Robert Wilson proved in a 1986 paper "Is $J_1$ a subgroup of the Monster" in Bull. London Math. Soc. 18, 349-150 that $J_1$ is not a subgroup, which was much more difficult at the time, because much less was known about the maximal subgroups of the Monster.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very interesting and helpful!

Comment: If $A$ is a subquotient of $B$ then is $A$ necessarily a subgroup of $B$?  If $A$ is a subgroup of $B$ then it seems it is automatically a subquotient of $B$.  Is that true?

Comment: Yes if $A$ is a subgroup of $B$ then it is automatically a subquotient of $B$. But the converse is not true. For example (as I said in a previous comment), the Baby Monster ${\rm B}$ is a subquotient of ${\rm M}$, but it is not a subgroup. It is the double cover $2.{\rm B}$ that is a subgroup of ${\rm M}$.

Comment: Great! Woah, I have no idea what the "double cover 2.B that is a subgroup of $M$" means, but that sounds so interesting.  Also, have you ever seen a 3D model of the happy family diagram?  I made one and it looks pretty neat!

Comment: @Erin it means that there is a 2-1 surjective group homomorphism $2.B \to B$ (using the notation used in the ATLAS), and an injective homomorphism $2.B \to M$. In particular, $2.B$ has $C_2$ as a central subgroup, hence isn't simple, but $B \simeq 2.B/C_2$ _is_ simple.

Comment: @DavidRoberts There is no injective homomorphisms $2.B \to M$. Perhaps you meant an injective homomorphism $C_2 \to 2.B$?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @DerekHolt then what does "It is the double cover 2.B that is a subgroup of M" mean, if not that $2.B$ is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of $M$?

Comment: @ErinCarmody you're welcome :-)